# pystan: CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, stan

Before I get to far into this, I should note that I have seen [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783755/pystan-distutils-errors-compileerror-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1), but the solution presented did not work for me.  Perhaps one reason why is because that was Linux build and my current difficulty is on a Windows 7 machine.  I use Cygwin to get access to the gcc (5.2.0) compiler suite.

In any event, I have been attempting to try out Stan via PyStan.  I am working with an Anaconda (2.4.1 64-bit) distribution which I just updated today (Python 2.7.11).  I initially tried to install PyStan via pip, but the install keeps failing due to what looks like the following error:

```
Cannot build msvcr library: "msvcr90d.dll" not found
```

Consequently, I used [conda](http://pystan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/windows.html) instead, which seemed to install just fine.  (I should note that the conda install pushed my numpy back to an earlier version, which created conflicts with the pandas upon import.  I just updated anaconda to deal with these broken dependencies.)  I was also able to import PyStan without any problems.  However, when I actually tried to fit a model (inside of a Jupyter Notebook), the process failed with the exception in the title.

The first thing I did was confirm that gcc was where in the referenced location (not shown in the title).  Indeed it was, and it seemed to working just fine.  I then tried to run the model as a script from the command line (still using Python), and it failed with the same error.  When I recreated the model via the REPL, it pointed to a different location that had a .bat file referencing the (verified) compiler, and that failed as well.

I am pretty sure this is because I have Visual Studio 2012, instead of Visual Studio 2008.  While it is possible for me to run parallel installations, if this code is going to be useful for others in the future, these are not reasonable hoops to jump through to make it happen.  I was hoping that someone else might have a better explanation.  Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably missing a Microsoft redistributable. Given your description, install the 2008 redistributable.

Comment: Not sure I know what you are referring to here.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'll let you choose which [Microsoft Download](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+2008+redistributable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) best works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Beneficial from the post at https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/306

I have met various error message, but finally, I install PyStan successfully.

My machine is also on Windows 7, x64 with Anaconda3 installed.Here are the procedures to install PyStan from the sourced codes.

1. Install Visual Studio 2017 & Visual Studio C++ Build Tool 2015 at http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
2. Update Conda

conda update conda

conda update --all

3. check the dependencies

pip install setuptool

conda install numpy cython matplotlib scipy pandas

4. Install gcc compiler components

conda install libpython

conda install -c msys2 m2w64-toolchain=5.3.0

5. created distutils.cfg file inside Anaconda3\Lib\distutils folder with the following:

[build]

compiler = mingw32

6. Download Git at https://git-scm.com/downloads

git clone --recursive https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan.git

7. Compile from the source code

python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32

python setup.py install

P.S. The solution for the issue: Cannot build msvcr library: "vcruntime140d.dll" not found.

Copy vcruntime140d.dll from C:\Windows\System32 to any folder, which is reachable in the path in the advanced system settings/environment variables/ system variables.